# Debug as soon as a process start

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, debugging, gdb

I am currently trying to debug a Cygwin compiled C++ Code via gcc in Windows and would want to attach as soon as the program launches. In order to do so, I launched `gflags` and configured to launch `gdb` when even the program is executed.

Unfortunately I would also want a visual debugger and am planning to use CDT (Eclipse C/C++ Plugin) to debug my program.

Is there a non-intrusive way (not modifying my program) to launch Eclipse and debug my program as soon as its launched.

**Attempt 1:** 
*(Determine if I can use gdbserver as the guest with Eclipse as a host. If it works, I can configure gflags to launch gdbserver)*

1. Downloaded the gdb source and did build the gdbserver
2. In Eclipse created a local connection

   1. Changed to the Remote System Explorer Perspective  [Windows -> Open Perspective -> Other -> Remote System Explore]
   2. Created a Local Connection
   3. Opened the New Connection Wizard Dialog [Remote System Explorer -> Connection]
   4. Selected Local as the Remote System Type
   5. Provided a connection name Bash (other options accepted as default)
3. Created a C/C++ Remote Application Debug Configuration

   1. [Run -> Debug Configuration -> C/C++ Remote Application]
   2. Selected the executable (in my case it was bash.exe)
   3. Added a Project Name (bash)
   4. Selected the Connection as Local
   5. Determined the port number from the Gdbserver Settings [Debugger -> GdbServer Settings]. In my case it was 2345.
4. Opened a command prompt and started gdbserver  `gdbserver :2345 bash.exe'
5. Switched back to Eclipse and Clicked on Debug on the Debug Configuration Dialog

Output:

In the console error message

```
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**Attempt 2** *(In Progress, create an Eclipse Plugin)*

Comment: Don't know about Eclipse but WinDbg allows non invasive debugging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh852365.aspx

Comment: @EdChum: WinDbg may not be a good debugger here as its not a cygwin compiled binaries via gcc so debug information may not be quite useful.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_debug_exes.htm

Comment: I don't have experience of Eclipse, but it may be possible to use the same technique that Visual Studio documents, by [adding a registry entry under Image File Execution Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/04/28/121871.aspx). See [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28vs.71%29.aspx) too.

Comment: @RogerRowland: Yes, gflags does the same things albeit without resorting to editing the registry. But, without [WinGDB](http://www.wingdb.com/), Visual Studio is useless in debugging cygwin compiled binaries.

Comment: Yes, I'm not suggesting using VS, but that same technique I have seen used to launch other applications automatically (even some trojans). In general, you can make it launch anyapp.exe with the name of the original exe passed as an argument. You'd just need to construct a suitable command, but that's where I run out of knowledge about Eclipse/cygwin.

Comment: @RogerRowland: Currently, I am using the technique to launch gdb via command prompt but what I intend to do is bring up Eclipse as a visual debugger.

Comment: Ok, I see, then I'm sorry I can't offer any more ....

Answer (score 1):

When starting a process manually there is an option to start it in a suspended state – the resulting process will have everything ready but not a single instruction of the primary thread will be executed (See CREATE_SUSPENDED flag for [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx))

I would write two little programs: one to start a particular process in a suspended state; other one to pick a particular process and call `ResumeThread`for the main thread.

The debugging scenario would then be:

- Create the target process suspended
- Attach the debugger
- Resume the process